# How to get column count of mergeare in excel vsto addin

Tags: c#, vsto

How to get the column count of the mergearea in excel?
I am using c# vsto addin.
Like in image how to get the column count of cell Sweep and AC IN/OUT?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: range.MergeArea.Columns.Count this returns column number..